# Postman utf-8 encoding issue when charset=utf-8 is not provided by server

Tags: spring, postman

Spring deprecated APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 (`application/json;charset=UTF-8`) annotation as they said:

```
     /**
     * A String equivalent of {@link MediaType#APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8}.
     * @deprecated as of 5.2 in favor of {@link #APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
     * since major browsers like Chrome
     * <a href="https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464">
     * now comply with the specification</a> and interpret correctly UTF-8 special
     * characters without requiring a {@code charset=UTF-8} parameter.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static final String APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

When I sent a request to API from Chrome or command line, encoding works correctly. But, Postman is not showing correct response unless I use `application/json;charset=UTF-8` for producing.

Is there any way to fix that issue on Postman?

Comment: It seems like Postman would need to support the spec by defaulting to Unicode, as described in the Chrome issue discussion.

Answer (score 2):

this has been solved in newer versions, upgrade if you still encounter the issue