# JSON localized strings retuned from API are invalid

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to get a JSON response form API call which return a localised strings. Works well in Postman with same setup as http calls. but when make an API call from application it returns weird string - please check below.

I tried passing header for supporting language but does not work

JSON response in Postman - `"text": "Número OMI-IMO",`
JSON response through application - `"text":"NÃºmero OMI-IMO"`

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
  login,
  headers: {'Consumer-Key': consumerKey, 'Accept-Language': '*'},
);
```

I have also tried setting my device default language to respective localized language in this case Spanish, local strings used int he application works fine.

Tried binding the string `"text": "Número OMI-IMO",` from JSON file works well.

The response re not working only with API response strings, its same with other language like Frensh, Portuguese.

Been trying different solution but nothing work this problem exist on both Android and iOS.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman utf-8 encoding issue when charset=utf-8 is not provided by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480399/postman-utf-8-encoding-issue-when-charset-utf-8-is-not-provided-by-server)

Comment: Adding header to api as 'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' worked for me, thank you for the insight.

Comment: body = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
if response has utf8 headers, use line above

Answer (score 0):

Import this dart lib on the head of the file

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert
```

then you do

```
String jsonString = convert.utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
```

Now you will have a proper formatted and decoded JSON